# Extract CAPITALIZED Words or words with numbers in it (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a database with articles and I want to extract capitalized words and words with number in them to create a list.  Here is an example :

" I, Duroux-Richard et al. will thus explain how circulating **micro-RNA**, and notably **miRNA-125b**, are potential valuable biomarkers in **RA** in “Circulating miRNA-125b is a potential biomarker predicting response to rituximab in rheumatoid arthritis.” Circulating levels of miRNA-125 may predict the response to rituximab in **RA** patients and their interest must therefore be reassessed by other teams to be used in daily clinical practice."

I want the output to be all of the words I bolded in the text.

Comment: what database? how do you read it? what programming language?

Comment: How do you decide which occurences of **RNA** not to match in your example? There are 2 occurences **not** in bold ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) `\w*[A-Z-0-9]+\w*` to select your text... Have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/vK9wN4/1): 
[image]

An other more complex alternative do not count first uppercase letters but count words with only uppercase letters will be this one: `(\b[a-z0-9]\w*[A-Z-0-9]+\w*)|(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b)`, [here](https://regex101.com/r/vK9wN4/1):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes that **words** as are text separated by "spaces".  Place the data in some cell, select the cell,  and run this macro:

```
Sub Xtractor()
    Dim t As String, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim CH As String
    t = ActiveCell.Text
    j = 1
    If InStr(t, " ") = 0 Then Exit Sub

    ary = Split(t, " ")
    For Each a In ary
        For i = 1 To Len(a)
            CH = Mid(a, i, 1)
            If CH Like "[0-9A-Z]" Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(j, 1).Value = a
                j = j + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next a
End Sub
```

It will create the list in the column to the right:

[image]

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Too lite as approach... split " " will split only spaces... see also "hello,MI250" or "Hello, mi-250" will give "Hello," there are a lot of word separators but spaces, like tabulations, commas, points, etc...

Comment: @Serge  You make a good point.......I will point out the limitation of my code.